# how to multiply 2 matrices (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiplication

Can anyone help me with this? I believe it's easy, but I don't know how to do it?

Create two matrices with elements `1,2,3,4,5` and `2,3,4,5,6` and matrix is 
multiply.

I have this, but I don't know how to multiply them:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(5).reshape(1,5)
b=np.arange(6).reshape(1,6)
print a
print b
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want element-wise multiplication, inner, outer products? Your code doesn't match your description.

Comment: Cannot be accomplished since matrix 1 has 5 columns and matrix 2 has 1 row. Unless you transpose the second matrix before multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

If you need mathematical matrix multiplication (dot product), use [numpy.dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) (see examples behind the link). Note that for `numpy.dot`, it DOES matter if the shape of your array is (5,1) or (1,5). You can transpose your array with `a.T` .

Comment: As the OP is already shaping the arrays, they could just `reshape(5, 1)` one of them

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that your arrays aren't what you think they are:

```
>>> np.arange(5).reshape(1, 5)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> np.arange(6).reshape(1, 6)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Instead, you probably want:

```
>>> np.arange(1, 6).reshape(1, 5)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.arange(2, 7).reshape(1, 5)
array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

You can then multiply them directly:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 6).reshape(1, 5)
>>> b = np.arange(2, 7).reshape(1, 5)
>>> a*b
array([[ 2,  6, 12, 20, 30]])
```

**Note** that this is for element-wise multiplication. For the dot product, see `leeladam`'s answer.